# How to put error inside modifier?

Tags: solidity, error, modifiers

Lets say i have this error:

```
error Main__ContractNotAllowed();
```

And also i have this modifier which checks this mapping:

```
mapping (address => bool) private isAllowed;

modifier onlyAllowedContracts() {
    require(isAllowed[msg.sender] == true);
    _;
}
```

Now i wanna put error inside this modifier which every time this function reverts ,this error shows up. is it possible? or i should do this in another way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can design it like this:

```
modifier onlyAllowedContracts() {
    if (isAllowed[msg.sender] != true) revert Main__ContractNotAllowed();
    _;
}
```

Comment: I figured out in this exact way couple minutes after posting this question, But thank you.